# Google Analytics Event tracking concern but gaq.push looks accurate

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to get the Big Red Button on the bottom of this page (http://emploiscentredappelscapitalone.ca/) to track clicks through Google Analytics Event tracking.  I have looked at the HTML and the gaq.push call looks accurate but it is not capturing.

"

Please let me know if there is something I am missing.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using Universal Analytics, but your onclick is using the older _gaq object, associated with classic GA, instead of the newer ga object, associated with UA. The onclick code should look like this:

```
onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'emploiscentredappelscapitalone_ca', 'Click', 'Apply_Online_Here');"
```

Hope that helps.